# mysql - Fix error "TypeError: 'long' object is not iterable"

Tags: python, mysql, flask, raspberry-pi, mysql-python

The error message:

```
TypeError: 'long' object is not iterable
```

Code pointed out in error message:

```py
def maxRowsTable():
    for row in x.execute("SELECT COUNT(temp) from sensors"): #this
        maxNumberRows=row[0]
    return maxNumberRows
```

My MySQLdb connection:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="user",
    passwd="pass",
    database="data"
)
x = conn.cursor()
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Your query only returns one row. Why do you need to read it in a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your query returns a single record, there is no need to iterate.

So:

```
x.execute("SELECT COUNT(temp) from sensors")
row = x.fetchone()
maxNumberRows = row[0]
```

Comment: `cursor.execute` returns an iterator that automatically fetches.

Comment: It should be `fetchone`. Python doesn't use camelCase.

Comment: Sorry but I'm a complete beginner. What is `x.fetchOne()` it said it's an AttributeError

Comment: Thanks for the fix @Barmar. I do need to improve my python skills...

Comment: Apparently my first comment is implementation-dependent. The standard Python cursor specification doesn't say what `cursor.execute()` returns. Some interfaces return an iterator, but apparently MysqlDB doesn't.